# Numbering - algorithm in a 2d array - "assign occurrence of a letter" - in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, linq

I need to create an algorithm in C# that basically counts the occurrence of a letter in the first column of an array and writes it into the 2nd column, for example:

```
a | 1 
a | 2 
b | 1 
c | 1 
a | 3 
b | 2 
b | 3 
c | 2 (...)
```

I feel like using LINQ would do the trick, but for now I cannot think of the correct way.

Two separate 1d arrays would do fine, too, as long as the indices match.

Thanks for hints and thoughts!

Comment: How would you give the input, via console or file or something?.

Comment: via file, but console or simply code as an example would be sufficient!

Comment: See answer of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19112/12097

Comment: @ja72: That's not what OP wants. He wants to keep all letters at their index but additionally he wants to know how often this letter already repeats in the array until this index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix types in a multi dimensional arrays. You could use `Dictionary<char,int>` instead where the key is the letter and the value is the occurence. However, that would not be the same as your `char[]` where letters can repeat.

So here is an approach than is more maintainable and readable using a custom `struct` with all relevant properties.

```
public struct LetterInfo
{
    public char Letter { get; set; }
    public int Occurence { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}:{1}->{2}", Index, Letter, Occurence);
    }
}
```

Given that you have already a `char[]` and you want to have all missing informations you could get them with `LINQ` in this way:

```
char[] letters = {'a', 'a' , 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'};
LetterInfo[] letterInfos = letters
    .Select((c, i) => new { Letter = c, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Letter)
    .SelectMany(xGrp => xGrp
        .Select((x, i) => new LetterInfo 
        { 
            Letter = x.Letter, Occurence = i + 1, 
            Index = x.Index 
        }))
    .OrderBy(li => li.Index)
    .ToArray();

string output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, letterInfos);
Console.Write(output);
```

Output:

```
0:a->1
1:a->2
2:b->1
3:c->1
4:a->3
5:b->2
6:b->3
7:c->2
```

Here's an approach without LINQ that should be more efficient but more memory-hungry (you can use `List<LetterInfo>` alone instead of the array to avoid another collection):

```
var latterList = new List<LetterInfo>();
var dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
{
    char c = letters[i];
    int occ = 0;
    dict.TryGetValue(c, out occ);
    dict[c] = ++occ;
    var li = new LetterInfo { Letter = c, Index = i, Occurence = occ };
    latterList.Add(li);
}
letterInfos = latterList.ToArray();
```

For the sake of completeness, here's the dictionary approach mentioned above to lookup a char and it's occurence:

```
Dictionary<char, int> letterCount = letters
    .GroupBy(l => l)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

If you want to know how often the letter `a` is in the array:

```
int aCount = letterCount['a'];  // throws an exception if a is not in the dictionary
```

or safer:

```
int aCount = 0;
bool contains = letterCount.TryGetValue('a', out aCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you would need a dictionary to keep track of your letters.

```
Dictionary<char, int> CharacterTracker
```

if we have

```
char[] characters
int[] occurrences
```

Then I would just iterate through `characters`. If we don't have that `character` in our Dictionary, then we put '1' in the corresponding `occurences` array, and `character` as a key in the Dictionary and 1 as its value. If we do have that character in our Dictionary, increment the value for the `Dictionary[character]`, and put that value in `occurences`

Answer (score 0):

This might be one of the cases where LINQ offers little benefit.

```
var letters = "aabcabbc";
var dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
var counts = letters.Select(letter =>
{
    int count;
    dict.TryGetValue(letter, out count);   // defaults to 0 if not found
    dict[letter] = ++count;
    return new { Letter = letter, Count = count };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory attempt in Linq (note: *not* a recommended solution!).  It's getting the result as an `IEnumerable<Tuple<char, int>>`...

```
char[] chars = "aabcabbc".ToCharArray();
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, chars.Length).Select(i => new Tuple<char, int>(chars[i], chars.Take(i + 1).Count(c => c == chars[i])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why using hammers to smash flies ? Use an array of counters indexed by letters. A dictionary brings no benefit here. And LINQ is a big sledgehammer.

Pseudocode:

```
: Initialize
for c in "a..z"
    counter[c]= 0

: Count    
for c in string
    counter[c]++
```